# Writing Files In NMinimize - Variables Not Evaluating

Tags: evaluation

I am trying to use minimization with an external process. To do this I need to write a file to be used as input for the external process. However, when a function that writes a value to file is called in `NMinimize` it writes unevaluated variables to the file. Here's an mwe:

```
mwe[a_, f_] := Module[{str},
  str = OpenWrite[f];
  WriteString[str, ToString[Round[a, 0.001]]];
  Close[str];
  a
  ]
```

Run function on its own:

```
f = CreateFile[];
mwe[10.0,f]
Import[f]
```

Which imports:

> 10. 

Now as part of `NMinimize`

```
NMinimize[
 Abs@mwe[a, f],
 {a}
 ]
Import[f]
```

Which imports as:

> Round[a, 0.001]

In this case the minimization only depends on the output of `mwe` so the minimization succeeds, but in the real case, I've got a file my external program can't read. I've tried forcing evaluation with `Evaluate`, or `ReleaseHold` but not with any clear picture of what is going on.

Comment: This happens because  `mwe[a, f]` evaluates once right at the start to `a`. `NMinimize` doesn't hold arguments. Try `mwe[a_?NumericQ, f_] := ...` instead after clearing the function.

Comment: That seems to have solved it.